# Problems with GWT designer when using my own composite base class

Tags: gwt

I want to use a base class for my composite forms rather than just directly inheriting from composite itself.  When I do this the GWT designer pukes on the sub-classes.

Here is my base class:

```
package com.mycompany.project.client.panels;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite;
import com.mycompany.project.client.PanelNotifyCallback;

public class PanelBase extends Composite
{
protected PanelNotifyCallback NextButtonNotify = null;
protected PanelBase THIS = this;

public void setNextButtonNotify( PanelNotifyCallback nextButtonNotify )
{
    NextButtonNotify = nextButtonNotify;
}
}
```

Here is a sub class:

```
package com.mycompany.project.client.panels.p2;


import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AbsolutePanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickHandler;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.DoubleBox;
import com.mycompany.project.client.panels.PanelBase;

public class Panel2 extends PanelBase
{

public Panel2()
{

    AbsolutePanel absolutePanel = new AbsolutePanel();
    initWidget(absolutePanel);
    absolutePanel.setSize("472px", "227px");

    Label lblPanel = new Label("Panel2");
    lblPanel.setStyleName("gwt-Label_Panel1");
    absolutePanel.add(lblPanel, 193, 88);
    lblPanel.setSize( "67px", "23px" );

    Button btnNext = new Button( "Next" );
    btnNext.addClickHandler( new ClickHandler()
    {
        public void onClick( ClickEvent event )
        {
        //  NextButtonNotify.Notify( THIS );
        }
    } );
    absolutePanel.add( btnNext, 196, 166 );

    Label lblPrice = new Label("Price:");
    absolutePanel.add(lblPrice, 35, 37);

    DoubleBox doubleBoxPirce = new DoubleBox();
    doubleBoxPirce.setName("PriceBox");
    absolutePanel.add(doubleBoxPirce, 75, 25);
}
}
```

And here is what happens when I open the design view for panel2.java

```
Exception during 'super' constructor evaluation
An exception happened during evaluation of constructor PanelBase() using arguments {}. 

java.lang.AssertionError: This UIObject's element is not set; you may be missing a call to either Composite.initWidget() or UIObject.setElement()
at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.UIObject.getElement(UIObject.java:556)
at com.mycompany.project.client.panels.PanelBase$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$9c1b2ca8.CGLIB$getElement$30(<generated>)
at com.mycompany.project.client.panels.PanelBase$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$9c1b2ca8$$FastClassByCGLIB$$1a67578f.invoke(<generated>)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:215)
```

Can I make my own base class and still have the designer work?  If so, what is wrong?  This is a fairly simple setup.  In the long run I also wanted to create some abstract base classes.

I can open the designer view for the base class, PanelBase.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the cause, the thing that causes the designer go choke.

protected PanelBase THIS = this;

That line.  If you make a copy of the "this" pointer in the base class, then the designer pukes when you try and open the design tab on the subclass.  Even if you do this assignment in the constructor it still pukes.

I do not think there is a work around.  I was just wanting to use the "this" pointer in some anonymous classes within the sub-classes.  I figured the base class would be a good holder for this reference.